# Maven ignoring properties defined on command line

Tags: maven

We have a multi-repo project, where we want to enable late definition of dependencies - where all modules in each repo are released with the same version. Thus, module A relies on B which in turn relies on C.
We specify in both A and B their dependency on C to be via a property `${repo3-Version}`. A however can have dependencies on other modules in repo3, which should also be `${repo3-Version}`

Inside B we have a default value for `repo3-Version` defined, mainly just to ease developer's lives.

The issue we see is that when building A we specify `-Drepo3-Version=x.y.z` on the command line, but the default value defined in B is still getting used when it pulls in C.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve the issue by moving the definition of the default value for `repo3-Version` into its own profile which is activated when `!repo3-Version` - in other words, only when that system property is not defined, do we define it.

I don't know where this behavior is defined, although it does make sense. The lookup for a dependency version property which is outside the reactor tries to resolve first within that's dependency hierarchy - only if it is not resolved there, does it check the command-line.